# renderer.writePDF doesn't work without error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios-simulator, nsfilemanager

I learn swift and faced with problem: when i try write pdf file in document directory nothing happened.
Code:

```
func createPDF() {
        // MARK: - create path
        let documentDir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .cachesDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
        let path = documentDir.appendingPathComponent("\(clientCompanyName + UUID().uuidString).pdf")

        // MARK: - create meta
        let pdfMetaData = [
            kCGPDFContextCreator: "something",
            kCGPDFContextAuthor: "https://bla-bla.com"
        ]
        let format = UIGraphicsPDFRendererFormat()
        format.documentInfo = pdfMetaData as [String: Any]
        
        // MARK: - set page size
        let pageWidth = 8.5 * 72.0
        let pageHeight = 11 * 72.0
        let pageRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: pageWidth, height: pageHeight)
        
        // MARK: - render
        let renderer = UIGraphicsPDFRenderer(bounds: pageRect, format: format)
        try? renderer.writePDF(to: path) { (context) in
            let attributes = [
                NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 72)
            ]
            let text = clientCompanyName + " " + formattedDate
            text.draw(at: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), withAttributes: attributes)
        }
    }
```

When i start this code, i don't see any errors in terminal. But if i open Files, my document didn't save

Comment: In general, don't  use `try ?`; it throws away errors.  Use `do/try/catch` and print the error you catch.  Also, this code is saving the file in the `caches` directory. This will not be visible to the user

Comment: @Paulw11, I tried use do/try/catch and .documentDirectory. And it doesn't work. catch-block doesn't catch errors

`
let documentDir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
        let path = documentDir.appendingPathComponent("\(clientCompanyName + UUID().uuidString).pdf")

....

        do {
            try pdfData.write(to: path)
            print("success write")
        } catch {
            print("Error->", error)
            fatalError("FATAL_ERR_FROM_CREATE_FILE_\(error)")
        }
`

Comment: So probably it is creating the file, but because you are writing it to the cache folder you can't see it.

Comment: @Paulw11 Ok. Thanks!
Can you suggest me a working method for correct save document in iPhone storage?

Comment: You probably just want [`documentDirectory`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager/searchpathdirectory/documentdirectory) not caches directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think the problem was that you were not allowed to write to the cachesDirectory. So replace everything with that, it should work. Also with with `pageDatas` you are now able to print in CGRects on multiple pages, just append the array, you're welcome :)

```
    func createPDF() -> URL {
            // MARK: - create path
        let documentDir = FileManager.default.temporaryDirectory
            let path = documentDir.appendingPathComponent("\("clientCompanyName" + UUID().uuidString).pdf")
        
            // MARK: - create meta
            let pdfMetaData = [
                kCGPDFContextCreator: "something",
                kCGPDFContextAuthor: "https://bla-bla.com"
            ]
        let format = UIGraphicsPDFRendererFormat()
        format.documentInfo = pdfMetaData as [String: Any]
        
        // MARK: - set page size
        let pageWidth = 8.5 * 72.0
        let pageHeight = 11 * 72.0
        let pageRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: pageWidth, height: pageHeight)
        
        // MARK: - render
        let renderer = UIGraphicsPDFRenderer(bounds: pageRect, format: format)
        let attributes = [
                NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 72)
            ]
        let text = "clientCompanyName" + " " + "formattedDate"
        let myAttributedString = NSAttributedString(string: text, attributes: attributes)
        let pageDatas = [[[pageRect, myAttributedString]]]
        let pdfData = createCustomPdfDataa(renderer: renderer, pageDatas: pageDatas)
        do {
            try pdfData.write(to: path)
        } catch {
            fatalError("Sorry this does not work, because \(error)")
        }
        return path
    }

    func createCustomPdfDataa(renderer: UIGraphicsPDFRenderer, pageDatas: [[[Any?]]]) -> Data {
        // render context to pdfData
        let data = renderer.pdfData { (context) in
            // create pages
            for pageNumber in 0..<pageDatas.count {
                context.beginPage()
                let pageData = pageDatas[pageNumber]
                for textIndex in 0..<pageData.count {
                    drawAttributedText(inFrame: pageData[textIndex][0] as! CGRect, pageData[textIndex][1] as! NSAttributedString)
                }
            }
        }
        return data
    }


    func drawAttributedText(inFrame: CGRect, _ text: NSAttributedString) {
        text.draw(in: inFrame)
    }
}
```

The createPDF function returns the url you are saving to, so call it with this code below if you want to display it in a PDFView:

```
    let documentDir = createPDF()
    let data = readDataFromUrl(with: documentDir)
    pdfView.document = PDFDocument(data: data)


func readDataFromUrl(with url: URL) -> Data {
    // PathUrl
    let fileURL = url
    // Read
    var readData = Data()
    do {
        readData = try Data(contentsOf: fileURL)
    } catch let jsonErr {
        print("Error read file:", jsonErr)
    }
    return readData
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But after copy-paste your code into mine. I still don't see any documents in "Files" (i tried: .cachesDirectory, .documentDirectory and temporaryDirectory). I don't need  display document. At the moment i want just save pdf to documents directory.
And as i see from this tutorial: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/writing-data-to-the-documents-directory

It shouldn't be a problem.